# How is Mac OS X Activity Monitor implemented? Can I use the same API?

Tags: macos

I'm looking at implementing a tool that looks at CPU usage on my Mac, similar to Activity Monitor, but I'm using the numbers in a calculation. I need to be able to get the CPU usage at 0.5 second intervals or so. What API does Activity Monitor use? Is it documented somewhere?

I'd rather not parse the output of command line programs if that's avoidable.

Comment: You could just poll on /proc/stat, parse the data, then do something with it. It's standard POSIX if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @tjameson There is no `/proc` at all on OS X.

Comment: You're right @ivanzoid, /proc is Linux specific. If the OP just wants the loadavg, [getloadavg](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getloadavg.3.html)  is the standard way to do it on BSD.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably find out by looking at the source for the Darwin version of the top command.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-73/libtop.c

This looks like it might be useful...

static kern_return_t
libtop_pinfo_update_cpu_usage(task_t task, libtop_pinfo_t* pinfo, int *state)